# how to create true/false table with given two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe with two columns like this:

```
group             user
group 1           user A
group 1           user B
group 1           user C
group 2           user B
group 2           user C
```

now i want to make it into a wide table. basically have a 1/0 value to indicate whether a user belongs to a group the desired outcome should look like (or have user as row and group as column):

```
            User A     User B     User C     User D
group 1        1         1         1           0
group 2        0         1         0           1
```

How can I do this? I tried looking up long table to wide, but seems like there requires a "value" but I dont have one. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can create a script in either php or some other language of your choice, query the first table, manipulate your data as you want in the new table and then run the insert queries on the new row data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One way:

```
 df.set_index('group')['user'].str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
         user A  user B  user C
group                          
group 1       1       1       1
group 2       0       1       1
```

## Second way:

```
df.groupby(['group','user'])['user'].count().unstack()
```

Output:

```
 user     user A  user B  user C
group                          
group 1     1.0     1.0     1.0
group 2     NaN     1.0     1.0
```

Comment: this is exactly what i needed! thank you! but why groupby(level=0)?

Comment: If you remove the groupby level=0 you will get multiple group1 and group2, so I group all like index values and sum.  Just comment that line out and execute you'll see the results.

Comment: okay so then the column group 1 group 2 etc will be distinct/unique values rather than repeats, am i understanding correctly?

Comment: also, why level = 0? i am reading this page here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html not so much info on the numbers you can set the level to. so what if it's level 1?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  And, then we sum those values associated with group1 and group2 together.

Comment: level=0 refers to the index, this is a single level index and it starts with zero.  If it were a multiindex, could group on any level.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering all my questions!! Really appreciate it